# Listing guilds discord.py

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord, discord.py

This is my code:

```python
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('CONSOLE: We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

      async def serverList():
        for guild in client.guilds:
          print(guild.id)

client.run(token)
```

I am trying to list the guild/servers the bot is in but this code does not work

Comment: Do you want the bot to list the guilds on startup or after using a specific command?

Comment: This is happening because `serverList()` is only defined and not called. Also if you want this to happen every time the bot starts, you don't need to define it as a function. Also remove the `async` if you are not going to use asynchronous code, it's not a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get your code to work you need to delete the line `async def serverList():` and correct indents so the `for` loop is on the same level with the very first `print('CONSOLE...`

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('CONSOLE: We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

    for guild in client.guilds:
        print(guild.id)

client.run(token)
```

Code does not run probably because of wrong indents - you have an extra unnecessary indent in your `async def serverList()`,

or if the problem that `guild.id`s do not get printed then is happening because you define the function with `async def` but you don't end up using it in your code.